# Accuracy of Google Maps geo-coordinates vs high precision GPS receiver

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, accuracy

I need to know how accurate coordinates obtained from Google Maps/Earth are. Are they 'quasi absolutely' (I know there is no absolut location determination)?

In other words, if I record the coordinates of a field object (e.g. a small tree or shrub in a meadow) using a two-frequency geodetic GPS receiver and I also obtain coordinates of the same object from Google Maps, are these lat and lon coordinates identical or is there a deviation between the coordinates recorded by high precision receiver and the coordinates derived from the software?

Sorry for my question, but I am not a GIS expert, just a biologist, so I am a little bit confused regarding that. I need to know it for field measurement purposes.

Comment: Depends largely on the size of the object, where it is located (a shrub in a park in downtown NY is better georeferenced than one somewhere in Siberia), the imagery creation date, the sensor used, the quality of the GPS signal on site, etc.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92008/accuracy-vs-precision-gps  and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306815/how-precise-is-gps

Comment: Thank you, Vince.